# HttpSession safe

Tags: security, session, servlets, httpsession

Where is servlet HttpSession stored?

Is it safe to store sensitive information in HttpSession attributes.

Can user maliciously modify session attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where HttpSession is stored depends on the application server implementation and the configuration selected by the deployer. Usually it is stored in memory, but many application servers allow you to persist it in a database. In any case the session is stored in the server and not in the client.

If as user you mean the client, then it is impossible for him/her to modify it, as it is stored server-side.